# Adding to a ListView with custom adapter with a Button press

Tags: java, android

I have a listview with a custom adapter, and I am trying to add steps to a list, however the  steps I try to add with a button press are not being added. I am very new to this so sorry if this is stupid.

ListClass
    public class RecipeListActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

```
RecipeAdapter myCustomAdapter;
List<String> myStepsList;
Button addTextButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe_list);

    final ListView recipeStepsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);


    myStepsList = new ArrayList<String>();


    myCustomAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(this, myStepsList);

    recipeStepsList.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);


    myCustomAdapter.add("Step 1");
    addToAdapter("Step 2");
    myStepsList.add("Step 3");

    final Button addTextStepButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);



   View.OnClickListener HandlerAdd = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("Step 4 should be added");
            addToAdapter("Step 4");

        }
    };

    addTextStepButton.setOnClickListener(HandlerAdd);





}

public void addToAdapter(String text)
{
    myCustomAdapter.add(text);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here step 1, 2 and 3 is added and shown in the list, and the sysout is printed, however step 4 is not added. If I call notifyDatasetChanged() in the button it crashes.

Custom Adapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private List<String> steps;
private Context myContext;
private LayoutInflater mlayout = null;



public RecipeAdapter(Activity context, List<String> mlist)
{
    this.steps = mlist;
    this.myContext = context;
    mlayout = (LayoutInflater) myContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return steps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return steps.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public void add(String text){
    this.steps.add(text);
}

public void updateRecipeList(List<String> newList)
{
    steps.clear();
    steps.addAll(newList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = convertView;
        recipeStepHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.recipe_text, null);
            viewHolder = new recipeStepHolder(v);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (recipeStepHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.recipeText.setText(steps.get(i));

        return  v;

}
}

class recipeStepHolder{
public TextView recipeText;
public recipeStepHolder(View base){
    recipeText = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
}
}
```

In short I want a press on addTextStepButton to add to the listview, but I am doing something wrong. Greatly appreciate any help!

Edit crashlog:

```
  07-07 19:14:50.508    1930-1930/com.example.cookclock.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL    EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.cookclock.app.RecipeAdapter.getView(RecipeAdapter.java:75)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2251)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1318)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1600)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This became a long post, but with a bit off hints from here I solved, by redoing my GetView in a much simpler way :

```
 public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = li.inflate(R.layout.recipe_text, viewGroup, false);
        TextView stepText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.recipeText);

        stepText.setText(steps.get(i).toString());

        return rowView;
```

Comment: when you add an item , you application should know that it should redraw the screen to display those newly added items. for this, you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter which I think you have missed. refer the answer given by Gabe Sechan below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
public void addToAdapter(String text)
{
    myCustomAdapter.add(text);
    myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

The extra line will tell the adapter to update the listview

Comment: This crashes the app.

Comment: Then you have some issues, probably in your add or getView.  Post the crashlog

Comment: It appears you are right, and there is something wrong with my GetView, I have added the crashlog to the original post.

Comment: You're never setting the tag on the view holder, so view.getTag is always null